# IIS CPU goes bezerk after updating web.config in a C# application with a Singleton with a thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-config, singleton

I have a web application that does the following:

You click a button to instantiate a singleton, which creates a Thread.  That Thread runs continuously doing some HTTP requests to gather some data.  You can click a stop button that calls the Abort() method on the thread and the application stops making HTTP requests.  When I start/stop it manually, everything works fine.

My problem occurs when ever I "touch" web.config.  The CPU (w3wp.exe process) spikes and the website stops responding.  Does anybody know why this is happening?  Shouldn't an update to web.config reset everything?

Sample code is below:

```
private static MyProcessor mp = null;
private Thread theThread = null;
private string status = STOP;
public static string STOP = "Stopped";
public static string START = "Started";

private MyProcessor()
{}

public static MyProcessor getInstance()
{
    if (mp == null)
    {
        mp = new MyProcessor();
    }
    return mp;
}

public void Start()
{
    if (this.status == START)
        return;

    this.theThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.StartThread));
    this.theThread.Start();
    this.status = START;
}

public void Stop()
{
    if (this.theThread != null)
        this.theThread.Abort();
    this.status = STOP;
}

private void StartThread()
{
    do
    {
        try
        {
            //do some work with HTTP requests
            Thread.Sleep(1000 * 2);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //retry - work forever
            this.StartThread();
        }
    } while (this.status == START);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is the problem:

```
private void StartThread()
{
    do
    {
        try
        {
            //do some work with HTTP requests
            Thread.Sleep(1000 * 2);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //The recursive call here is suspect
            //at the very least find a way to prevent infinite recursion
            //--or rethink this strategy
            this.StartThread();
        }
    } while (this.status == START);
}
```

When your app domain resets, you'll get a ThreadAbort exception which will be caught here and trigger a recursive call, which will hit another exception, and another recursive call. It's turtles all the way down!

Comment: Thanks, I commented out the line to re-call the thread and the problem was solved.  Obviously a bad implementation on my part... now the killer question: what is my alternative?  Essentially, I am trying to keep a Thread going forever... even if it throws some exceptions (eg HTTPException or something similar).  Basically, I don't want it to stop everytime it has a hickup, but certainly when the application is reset.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I've recently set up something for a similar situation, but with a different approach. I had a restart thread blocking on a special restart event that was set each time an exception was encountered, but no recursion. It's always possible to unwind recursive structures into loops, and that's what I'd recommend here. If you must recurse, keep a count of how many calls you've made using a static variable, and set a fail-safe number beyond which you won't make the recursive call. You should also be looking for exceptions that are specific to an AppDomain reset and avoid recursions in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, making any change in web .config resets the application, and asp.net re-build the application.

Same is true for some other files like files under Bin and App_Code folders.

Comment: Thanks, but why does w3wp.exe go bezerk when I do this?